# Можно ли сказать: "Речь про ..."?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, предлоги

Можно ли сказать "Речь про" в  предложении "Если **речь про** официальное предложение"?

Answer (score 2):

В литературе действительно предлог "про" встречается очень часто. Но обычно рекомендуют употреблять предлог "о". Вот что отвечает Грамота.ру на подобный вопрос.

> Скажите, какой предлог правильнее использовать — "про" или "о": "про
>   погоду" или "о погоде", "про любовь" или "о любви", "про Пушкина" или
>   "о Пушкине"?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Общеупотребимый предлог — *о*. Предлог *про* несёт разговорный
>   характер.

Answer (score 2):

*Можно* так сказать, но в определённом контексте: употребление предлога "про" вместо "о" с соответствующим падежом обычно указывает на то, что собеседникам *известен аспект*, в котором будет идти речь о *названном предмете* (сам аспект может намеренно не называться).

В нашем случае, если об официальном предложении речь ранее не заходила, употребление предлога "про" было бы необоснованным. Но в другой ситуации, например, если какое-то время шли переговоры и стороны продолжают рассматривать несколько неофициальных предложений по контракту и одно *официальное* (напр. единственное письменное), то речевым оборотом с предлогом "про" вполне можно сослаться на *уже существующее* официальное предложение, содержание которого сторонам известно (такая ссылка была бы самодостаточна), а не на новое или неопределённое (как в варианте с предлогом "о").

**P.S.** Посмотрел, что пишут об этом. До недавнего времени на эту тему было принято лишь цитировать Розенталя: "*предлог **про** вводит разговорный оттенок*". Но появились работы, в которых разграничивается функциональная роль предлогов **о** и **про**.

> Предлог **о** вводит роль **темы сообщения**, в то время как предлог **про**
>   вводит **две** роли: роль **темы сообщения** и дополнительную роль **содержания**
>   **сообщения**.

https://iling.spb.ru/confs/rusconstr2011/materials/Dubrovina_poster.doc

Здесь (см. стр. 2) содержание сообщения имеет тот же смысл, что и упомянутый мной "*аспект*".

Answer (score 1):

Предлоги О/ОБ и ПРО могут различаться по своей семантике (а не только по нейтральному и разговорному стилю): **о чем** — это общее описание предмета, взгляд со всех сторон; **про что** — короткое указание на суть предмета.

Поэтому выбор предлога может зависеть от контекста:

1) **Речь идет про официальное предложение** (это означает, что были еще неофициальные разговоры).

2) **Речь идет об официальном предложении**, сделанном правительством (это общее представление).

**Пример из Нацкорпуса (о семантике и стиле предлога ПРО):**

― Значит, про что, **грубо говоря**, спектакль Васильева? [Поэт и толпа (2003) // «Театральная жизнь», 2003.07.28]

**Про что**: очень коротко назовите тему.  **Грубо говоря**:  желательно без подробного анализа и   извините за "разговорный предлог".

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Примеры из Нацкорпуса русского языка:

**Речь про** Россию для России, если только уже не поздно. [Надежда Кожевникова. Русский гроб-ковчег (2003) // Интернет-альманах «Лебедь», 2003.07.21]

Вот рассудите. **Речь про** какого-то Буркина, фотографа-любителя ... Борис Пастернак в двадцатые годы // «Звезда», 2003]

Но должен заметить: то, что Вы называете предложением, вряд ли является таковым, скорее всего, это часть предложения. Возможно, в полном предложении лучше сказать: "... речь **идет** про ..."